# Android studio java - Toast

Tags: android

> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text: "Value has been
> decremented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

I get an `error` whenever I type this `code` and my `app` is not running. What can I do?

Comment: You should also provide your code and the error you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass activity context. **this** or **ActivityName.this** or **getActivity** because application instance is tied to the lifecycle of the application, while the Activity instance is tied to the lifecycle of an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You must delete the word "text" or replace the following line

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value has been decremented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Toast.makeText(this,"Value has been decremented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: This might be answer of the question. But, try adding some information what you are doing. Explain him how it is working...

Answer (score 0):

when you want create a `Toast` you should put correct info in their...

in `Toast` in first parameter put your activity or context you use if you use `Toast` in your java class create a `context` and for that create `constructor` and use the `context` in first parameter and if you want use that in `fragment` you can use `getActivity` or `getContext` and in activity you should use `ActivityName` or `ActivityName.this` anyway...